# Terminal Stdin on multiple lines

Tags: terminal

How do I get my stdin to be multiple lines? For example, I want my input to be

0 1,4
1 4,5
6 3,5

Whenever I type one line of this and hit enter, it runs my code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When I type a line and then hit Ctrl+M it will take me to the new line and then Ctrl+D will run the program with those inputs